# How to make php while loop out of this MySQL query?

Tags: php, html, mysql, while-loop

I want to make a loop so that every time the 'id' is queried, it puts the data into a separate block. Imagine it like listings on ebay. I know the foreach wont do it, but i have no idea how to do the while loop.

```
<?php
include 'sqlconnection.php';
$conn = OpenCon();

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id from tasks where status='o'");
$stmt->execute();
$res = $stmt->get_result();
$data = $res->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

foreach ($data as $row) 
{
     echo    "<p>" . $row['id'] . "</p>";   
}
CloseCon($conn);
?>
```

This is the HTML block i want to repeat:

```
    <div class="listing-header">
        <div class="listing-title">
          <p>       </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to look at this:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT id from tasks where status=?'); $o = 'o';
$stmt->bind_param('s', $o); $stmt->execute(); $stmt->bind_result($id); $html = '';
while($stmt->fetch()){
  $html .= '<div class="listing-header"><div class="listing-title"><p>'.$id.'</p></div></div>';
}
$stmt->close(); $conn->close();
```

**in HTML**

```
<?=$html?>
```